# print X O in pyramid pattern in java?

Tags: java

I want output to be like:

```
X
X O
X O X
X O X O
X O X O X
```

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
            {
                if (j==0 || j==2 || j==4) {
                    System.out.print("X ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("O ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
     }
}
```

But my output is like this:

```
X O X O X 
X O X O X 
X O X O X 
X O X O X 
X O X O X
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your `if` can be shortened to just `if (j%2==0)`. It's a general check to see if a number is divisible by 2. Can be useful if you want a bigger pyramid later.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have this

```
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
```